# unallocated space added under sda3, how to add it to sda5 now (gparted)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have an SSD with unallocated space of 18gb, and `/` directory of 10.40 gb, and the rest is being used for windows. I decided to add some of the unallocated space to my `/` directory.

I ran linux through my flash drive, I opened **gparted**, and I resized **sda3** to take up 13.00 gb of the 18.4 gb unallocated space. That worked, now I would like to add that 13.00gb unallocated under **sda3** to **sda5** **ext4** which is the root directory. How can I do that with gparted ?

here is a picture of how it looks now:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the swap partition (/dev/sda6), resize your root partition (/dev/sda5) by 13 Gb, create a new swap partition in the remaining space on /dev/sda3.

Comment: So I can only resize root partition(/dev/sda5) by removing swap partition ? and why is that ?

Comment: Because to resize a partition you need a continuous block of free space immediately after the partition you're going to resize. Instead of deleting and recreating the swap you can try moving it, but I don't think it's worth it because swap contains no useful data anyway.

Comment: hey awesome I was able to resize sda5 to about 22 GB. I left 1.8 gb of unallocated space in case swap needs to use it. How do I create new swap partition in the remaining space on /dev/sda3

Comment: You right-click on the un-allocated space and select "New". Then you select Linux swap as the type of the new partition.

Comment: That did it thank you very much. Also is there a reason why there is a warning on /dev/sda1 which is my windows partition. The warning says `/dev/sda1 does not exist`. I just want to make sure I will not delete any data from my windows before moving forward

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why the warning is there - I don't dual-boot Linux and Windows.